# Why converting float to float16 creates unnecessary values?

Tags: python, numpy, precision, numpy-ndarray

Why when I perform

```
g = np.float16([4.4,4.6])
```

I get something different

```
g  = [4.3984..., 4.6015...].
```

Will it somehow affect calculations with the matrix? Can I change this behavior without changing dtype?
Thanks!

Comment: You chose to use a more limited precision than usual floats, so you get the closest value that can be represented by you data type. And so yes, this will affect calculations.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `>>> np.float16([4.4,4.6])` returns `array([4.4, 4.6], dtype=float16)`. I had to use `float(g[0])` to get `4.3984375`.

Comment: In any case, floating point numbers can't represent every rational number. `4.4` can't be represented exactly. Neither can `0.3`. Numpy's `float16` does extra work to handle this when printing. Internally though, the number is still `4.3984375`. If you try `np.float16(4.3984375)` you'll get `4.4`

Comment: `np.float16(4.3984375)==4.3984375 ` is True, while `np.float16(4.3984375)==4.4` is False because `float16` is storing `4.3984375` internally

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to cast `float16` back to a `float` to get that result. You aren't getting a different result though, that's the actual value.

You can't represent `4.4` or `0.3` and many other rational numbers with a floating point number, no matter the precision. Python itself doesn't store `4.4` :

```
>>> f"{4.4}" 
'4.4'
>>> f"{4.4:.15f}" 
'4.400000000000000'
>>> f"{4.4:.20f}" 
'4.40000000000000035527'
```

The reason that `4.4` prints as `4.4` is that 15 is the default print precision according to the IEEE 754 floating point number standard.

Using a smaller type increases the error :

```
>>> f"{np.float64(4.4):.20f}" 
'4.40000000000000035527'
>>> f"{np.float32(4.4):.20f}" 
'4.40000009536743164062'
>>> f"{np.float16(4.4):.20f}" 
'4.39843750000000000000'
```

NumPy